# Is the Jacobi theta function invertible?

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, modular-forms, theta-functions

Let $\theta$ denote the Jacobi theta function:
$$\theta=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{(-1)^kq^{k(k+1)}sin((2k+1)\frac{2\pi}{\omega_1}Re(z))},$$
 and we have a complex number $t$. Suppose that we know there exists a complex number $\tau\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $t=\theta(\tau)$. Is there an algorithm which can find $\tau$?

Indeed I have an elliptic curve $E$ (so I have $q$) and $\theta(z(P))$, where $P\in E(\mathbb{Q})$, I want to recover $P$ from the theta function!

Comment: Which Jacobi theta function?  There are four of them, and they are functions of two variables.  They are certainly not one-to-one.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't know there is four of them! I changed my question to clarify! Thanks for your attention!

Comment: How do you "have $\theta(z( P))$" without knowing $P$?

Comment: Normally there would be no "Re" in the definition.  If it's there, how do you expect to find the imaginary part of $z$?

Comment: I have some relations which help me to find $\theta(z(P))$, I know $z\in\mathbb(R)$, so $Re(z)=z$.

Comment: Indeed I have a special elliptic curve and I found the relations for this curve.